# Can't load Memcache library in LAMPP

Tags: php, memcached

I've spent last couple of hours trying to add the Memcache extension to my PHP (on LAMPP, using Ubuntu 11.10 amd64).

I followed [this](http://www.scribd.com/scribd4krisna/d/19031683-XAMPP-Memcache-Extension) to tutorial (and some others), always I had errors:

1. Warnings on step-5:

   > configure.in:3: warning: prefer named diversions
   >
   > configure.in:3: warning: prefer named diversions
2. Warning on step 7:

   > XAMPP: Stopping Apache...
   >
   > Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 in Unknown on line 0
   >
   > Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 in Unknown on line 0
   >   XAMPP: Starting Apache...

Can anyone please help me solve this issue? I haven't been able to find any solution to this problem which worked for me. Thanks for your time.
The commands are as given:

**Edit:**
Command that led to first 2 warnings (ran both the commands inside the memcache folder which was created on extracting the tar folder via the **tar -xzf** command):

> /opt/lampp/bin/phpize

Command which led to the second 2 warnings:

> /opt/lampp/lampp restartapache

Comment: On way to solve this, is that you explain in your own words what "warning: prefer named diversions" exactly means. If you don't know, do some research first and then try to explain as best as you can. Also add the commands that lead to the error as well in this question, so it's clear to what action that error message is about w/o needing to read some other site.

Comment: I couldn't find anything useful about the "named diversions". Since the error refers to the line 3, so here it is **#undef COMPILE_DL_MEMCACHE**. I have also put the commands in my question now.

Comment: And the comment before that line is "Whether to build memcache as dynamic module".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed [the tutorial about Installing memcached on ubuntu 10.04](http://www.zayinkrige.com/installing-memcached-on-ubuntu-10-04/) and was able to set up memcache on my machine. After setting it up, I used

```
sudo /etc/init.d/memcached restart ; sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

command to load both services (apache and memcache). You may see [this tutorial](http://www.bookofzeus.com/articles/how-to-install-memcached-in-ubuntu/) as well.

I put my pages at the location `/var/www`.